# Classification of line bundles by second cohomology of a manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, line-bundles, derham-cohomology

In the book Loop spaces, Characteristic classes and geometric quantization by Brylinski I see following result when trying to motivate geometric description of $H^3(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

> $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is the group of isomorphism classes of line bundles over $M$.

I guess they mean there is a natural isomorphism.

Can some one give a rough idea of what obvious second cohomology class we can think of given a line bundle over $M$ and what line bundle can we think of given an arbitrary second cohomology class.

Intuitive comments are also welcome.

I am familiar (not the proof details) with following result:

> If $G$ is a group and $M$ is a $G$-module, then the  $H^2(G, A)$ is in one-one correspondence with the set of
>   equivalence classes of extensions $E$ of $M$ by $G$, in which the action of $G$ on $M$ induced by conjugation in $E$ is the same as the action defined by the $G$- module $M$.

I am expecting some intuitive explanation that looks similar to this.

Comment: H^2(M,Z) classifies complex line bundles with respect to tensor product, by the first Chern class. One can find the isomorphism using the exponential sequence, found in any introductory text on complex algebraic geometry.

Comment: @TobiasShin Yes, that is true. Given a complex line bundle, we can associate first(and only) chern class which gives an element of $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$.. Can you give some reference whose  proof you like it better than others..

Comment: @TobiasShin Can you make your comment as an answer.. I can upvote..

Comment: @users who want to close. Reason some one mentioned for their close vote is "This question does not appear to be about research level mathematics within the scope defined in the help center." I can not argue that this is a research level question. I believe this is serious question. I am ok if you think otherwise but can you wait till Tobias responds for my comment and makes his comment as an answer.. Then you can close it..

Comment: It's possible that this was all supposed to be obvious to me, and it's certainly all familiar in broad strokes, but I upvoted the question and all of the answers.

Comment: @PaulSiegel that’s very nice .. thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ cannot mean the de Rham cohomology group. The coefficients are wrong.

Anyway: $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ is an amazing space. It is both a model for $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ and a model of $BU(1)$. Homotopy classes into $K(\mathbb Z,2)$ is in bijection with $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ (By pulling back the fundamental class) and homotopy classes into $BU(1)$ classify (complex) line bundles (by pulling back the tautological bundle). This works well with natural group structures. This gives the required isomorphism.

The cohomology class in $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ corresponding to the complex line bundle is the first Chern class.

I can recommend Milnor Stasheff "characteristic classes" for the classification of the line bundles. I can recommend Hatcher for the classification of cohomology in terms of homotopy classes into $K(\mathbb Z,n)$.

Comment: After identifying deRham cohomology with singular cohomology...

Comment: The point is that the coefficients are wrong. De Rham cohomology is isomorphic with the singular cohomology with $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients. This does not recover the cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You can also look at Chern-Weil theory if you want to stay in the de Rham world.

Comment: :D :D I am very sorry.. I do not know what I was thinking when I said that... Yes, you are right.. isomorphism is from $H^2_{dR}(M)$ to $H^2(M,\mathbb{R})$..

Comment: Can you explain your comment “you can look at Chern-Weil theory if you want to stay in deRham world”...

Comment: Using connections one can define the curvature of a line bundle. This gives you a way of constructing a first Chern class in the de Rham theory. If I remember correctly it does not see torsion, but it is a long time since I thought about this.

Comment: I am actually interested in that perspective only..  when you are free can you think of some reference and let me know..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I like the appendix on Chern-Weil theory in Milnor and Stasheff's book.

Comment: I am trying to understand your second paragraph... you are saying there is a bijection $[M,K(\mathbb{Z},2)]\rightarrow H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}$ and a bijection $[M,BU(1)]\rightarrow Vect^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$ and as $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is same as that of $BU(1)$ you are saying there is a bijection $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow Vect^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$... am I correct?? I know the result about $BU(1)$ and line bundles (for example you can see that in Allen Hatcher vector bundles K theory theorem $1.16$).. I am not familiar with the result about $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ and cohomology. Can you please give reference

Comment: It is in Hatcher's book (brown representability is a keyword)

Comment: You mean Hatcher’s algebraic topology (I have mentioned another book of Hatcher, so I was confused).. yes, it is there in Hatcher’s algebraic topology, page 393, theorem $4.57$ (online version)... thanks... I was expecting deRham cohomology version but this is more interesting than what I was expecting.. so accepting this answer...

Comment: Can $M$ be just a topological space? Not necessarily a manifold? I think it is not necessarily a manifold...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: There are some conditions on niceness of spaces I think. Like CW and paracompactness are some keywords. Look in the references for precise statements.

Comment: Can't seem to easily find classification of line bundles in Milnor-Stasheff. Searched on both "line bundle" and "chern class"...

Comment: They prove it in general. Vector bundles are classified by maps in grassmannians. It is in the first few chapters

Answer (score 12):

For what it is worth, here is another approach, in the algebraic geometry style. By taking out the zero section, complex line bundles correspond bijectively to $\mathbb{C}^*\!$-principal bundles on $M$. Such bundles are classified by the cohomology group $H^1(M, \mathcal{O}_M^*)$, where $\mathcal{O}_M$ is the sheaf of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ complex-valued functions on $M$. Now there is an exact sequence of sheaves
$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_M\xrightarrow{\ \mathbf{e}\ }\mathcal{O}_M^*\rightarrow 1 $$where $\mathbf{e}(f):=\exp(2\pi if)$.
This gives rise to a cohomology exact sequence 
$$H^1(M, \mathcal{O}_M)\longrightarrow H^1(M, \mathcal{O}_M^*)\xrightarrow{\ \partial \ } H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow H^2(M, \mathcal{O}_M)\,.$$But since $\mathcal{O}_M$ is a fine sheaf, its higher cohomology vanishes, and $\partial $ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I saw this approach some time back... Thanks for your answer +1.. Do you have any specific references in your thought where this is done in a better way than others?? It is done in Brylinkski's Loop spaces, Characteristic classes and Geometric quantization (I did not read that seriously though)...

Comment: That exact sequence you gave has nothing to do with "holomorphic" functions right?? Given a $\mathbb{C}$ valued smooth function $f$ on $U$ you are considering the function $exp(2\pi if)$ which is non vanishing function on $U$... That is it right?

Comment: Yes, this is right. And as I say in my answer, $\mathcal{O}_M$ is the sheaf of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ complex-valued functions on $M$ — sorry if my notation is confusing.
.

Answer (score 5):

Although Milnor and Stasheff is an excellent suggestion, I was also led to wonder where one would find this result in more recent textbooks.  Most ingredients are in May's "Concise introduction to algebraic topology".  Specifically, May proves on page 177 that $H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})\simeq [X,K(\mathbb{Z},2)]$.  Here $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is officially defined as $B^2(\mathbb{Z})$, where $B$ is the simplicial classifying space functor.  However, on page 121 May gives a sequence of exercises about Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.  As a special case, we find that whenever $Z$ is a connected CW complex with $\pi_2(Z)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_i(Z)=0$ for $i\neq 2$, we have $Z\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.  In particular, it is not hard to find fibrations whose long exact sequences prove that the spaces $Z=BU(1)$ and $Z=\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ have the required homotopy groups, so they are both homotopy equivalent to $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.  May also proves on page 197 that the set of isomorphism classes of line bundles on $X$ is naturally identified with $[X,BU(1)]$.

Comment: One reference would be Husemoller's "Fibre bundles". In the 3rd edition  it is theorem 3.4 in Chapter 17, p.250.

Comment: Thanks, I never saw that book carefully.. This gives enough reason to see that with care :) :) Thanks again... +1